# Div Inside Container not shrinking

Tags: css

I have a container with 960px and i want the divs inside this container to shrink as i change the browser size

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="firstDiv">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href=""><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-2x"></i> </a></li>
                <li> <a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i> </a></li>
                <li> <a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i> </a></li>
                <li> <a href=""><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i> </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="secondDiv">
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="search">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End of Container -->
```

and css goes like this

```
.container{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.firstDiv {
    height:100px;
    width:70%;
    float:left;
}
.secondDiv {
    height:100px;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
}
```

how can i make these two dives to adjust according to my container div as i shrink my browser size

Answer (score 1):

The divs won't shrink because

```
.container { 
    width: 960px; 
}
```

To let the divs resize you need to not have a fixed width.

Try

```
.container { 
    max-width: 960px; 
}
```